# How do I make a model with a datetime field that does NOT save the time zone?

Tags: django

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class IPLog(models.Model):
    last_click = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I save an `IPLog` instance, the time zone gets saved with it. This is a problem for me since I want to compare `last_click` to a `datetime.now()` instance, but it throws me an error since the model instance's `last_click` has a time zone: `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`.

The difference tends to look like this:

```
2018-03-16 00:24:35.619424 # datetime.now()
2018-03-15 23:55:07.006190+00:00 # last_click
```

How do I stop my model from saving new instances with a time zone?

Comment: If you get last_click in database directly,you can try set `USE_TZ = False` in `settings.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing to `datetime.now()` you should compare to `timezone.now()`:

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
```

You can read more about timezone aware datetime objects [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects).